# How data propagates in Google Cloud Platform the moment I connect to GCP from ssh console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

Wanted to know how the data propagates via Google Network. This is my understanding. Correct me if I am wrong.

I open https://console.cloud.google.com in India, Bangalore using an internet service provider named ABC. In the cloud console, I ssh into a compute engine which is provisioned in Asia-SouthEast1-a (Singapore) datacenter/ zone. If I upload a 5MB into this compute engine from my laptop how does the data flow? My understanding is

Step 1: Since, data is uploaded from Bangalore the nearest Points of Presence is Mumbai. The data travels to Mumbai Points of Presence enters Google Network.

Step 2: From Mumbai Points of Presence data travels through the Google network and reaches Singapore data center.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Based on this Gif image https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-J5Rtu3UWlLc/WyKx2k77kgI/AAAAAAAAF30/qyT_LFgQiI8y5TbRYYxsOkuRcIi_v6ItwCLcBGAs/s1600/gcp-partner-interconnect.gif it looks like my understanding is correct

Answer (score 0):

Google's [network infrastructure](https://peering.google.com/#/infrastructure) has three distinct elements which span all over the world:
* Core data centers
* Edge Points of Presence (PoPs)
* Edge caching and services nodes (Google Global Cache, or GGC)

Google's strategy is using DNS based mechanism to serve customers from the nearest location possible to improve the performance. You could watch this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWpBNm6lBU4) how Google’s network evolves to improve customer experience.